# Cannot set PowerShell result in output file

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am writing a PowerShell script to call another PowerShell script from another machine using `Invoke-Command` and execute that script. I have output code in my PowerShell console, but I can not put that output to CSV file. I put `Invoke-Command` in a variable, but variable is empty. Can anyone help me?

I tried `Export-Csv` and `Output-File`.

```
function Get-Result {
    &"C:\Users\dnaInstaller\Desktop\AuthentiCode.ps1"
}
$allMessage = Invoke-Command -ComputerName core1rt2 -ScriptBlock ${function:Get-Result}
$allMessage | Export-Csv "C:\Users\Desktop\test.csv" -Append
```

Expected result: Created CSV file with result like in PowerShell console.
Actual result: Empty CSV file.

Comment: The output path looks wrong; `C:\Users\Desktop\test.csv"`.  Going by the path earlier in the script, it should probably be this: `C:\Users\dnaInstaller\Desktop\test.csv"`

Comment: I tried this C:\Users\dnaInstaller\Desktop\test.csv", it's not the problem

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem - while the path does need fixed, if `$allMessage` is empty it won't matter.  Is the script `Authenticode.ps1` located on the local system or the remote one?

Comment: Authenticode.ps1 is located on remote machine, but I want to run and catch output in local machine in csv file.

Comment: I made problem by myself. AuthentiCode.ps1 script was not with return value.